# why do we use abstract classes in clean architecture?

Tags: flutter, dart, clean-architecture

we have abstract classes in clean architecture where we just define functions and then write the whole code in an implementation class that implements those functions.
why not use only the second function?

abstraction

```
abstract class PriceTrackerDataSource {
  Stream<dynamic> getActiveSymbols();
}
```

implementation

```
class PriceTrackerDataSourceImpl implements PriceTrackerDataSource {
  @override
  Stream<dynamic> getActiveSymbols() async* {
    if (_ws != null) {
      await _ws!.sink.close();
    }

    _connect();
    yield* _ws!.stream;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes are used to make each layers more independent (data, domain, presentation). And also to define main methods for the own classes

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes help us to define a template / common definition for our multiple derived classes also reducing code duplication.

Making the class abstract ensures that it cannot be used on its own, but the details must be defined in the derived class implementation.

For more explanation you can have a look at [Dart Docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#abstract-classes).

Comment: I guess the question was about a situation when abstract class has only one implementation. And in this case I personally do not see a reason to make abstract class, do you?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a reason to make abstract class just for a single implementation (even in future cases). In case someone wants to add something later on, it may be helpful.